# Удалить элемент ассоциативного массива по значению?

Tags: php, массивы

собств. сабж. Нужно это сделать так, чтобы не оставалось пустых элементов после этого.

п.с. возможно тема уже в 100-й раз поднимается, но не оказалось у меня под рукой функции, в гугле в основном одномерные примеры.

Да, и еще, ключ заранее неизвестен как вы уже догадались.

Массив имеет вид $arr = array('key1'=>array('foo'=>'znachenie'),.. и т.д.

Comment: А как далее? ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Функция для удаление элементов из массива $array по значению $value с рекурсивным спуском

function deleteItem( &$array, $value )
{
    foreach( $array as $key => $val ){
        if( is_array($val) ){
            deleteItem($array[$key], $value);
        }elseif( $val===$value ){
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }
}

// Пример:

$arr = array(
    'key1'=>'value1',
    'key2'=>array(
        'key21'=>'value21',
        'key22'=>'value22',
        'key23'=>'value23',
    ),
    'key3'=>'value3',
);

deleteItem($arr, 'value22');
```

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно понял проблему, то необходимо использовать рекурсивный обход массива с проверкой на [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php). В рекурсивную функцию элемент передавать по ссылке и в случае пустого значения удалять его.